# Xamarin.Forms Android keeping the hamburger/menu icon instead of the Back button

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Is there a way to keep the hamburger/menu icon in Xamarin.Forms Android while using a Flyout Navigation and the navigation stack enabled? I use a custom renderer on iOS to have the Back button and the Menu button there but Android would only need the Menu button because the system already has a back button. Any hint or help would be really helpful because I can't find anything relevant on Google.

Comment: If you want to change the page after you choose menu, you just simply change the `Detail` property of your `FlyoutPage` or `MasterDetailPage` without need to push navigate

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way to work around this, it works for now even if it is not the cleanest way:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.iOS)
{
    FormsApp.GetCurrentNavigationPage().Pushed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(e.Page, false);
    };
}
```